# Java - Accessing Secure HTTPS Third Party API

Tags: java, maven

I am editing a Java application and trying to access a secure third party API.  There are two String variables that need to be passed, and ID and a token for the secure access.  The code below is using Maven.  I am trying to tweak the code for just Java.

```
public class JavaApiStreaming {
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException {

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    try {

        // Set these variables to whatever personal ones are preferred
        String domain = "https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com";// trying to access this api
        String access_token = "ACCESS-TOKEN"; //using this token
        String account_id = "1234567";  //using this ID 
        String instruments = "EUR_USD,USD_JPY,EUR_JPY";
```

// This is the part of the code I am trying to edi.  to my knowledge this is //maven coding
            HttpUriRequest httpGet = new HttpGet(domain + "/v1/prices?accountId=" + account_id + "&instruments=" + instruments);
            httpGet.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token));

```
        System.out.println("Executing request: " + httpGet.getRequestLine());

        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

        if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && entity != null) {
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                Object obj = JSONValue.parse(line);
                JSONObject tick = (JSONObject) obj;

                // unwrap if necessary
                if (tick.containsKey("tick")) {
                    tick = (JSONObject) tick.get("tick");
                }

                // ignore heartbeats
                if (tick.containsKey("instrument")) {
                    System.out.println("-------");

                    String instrument = tick.get("instrument").toString();
                    String time = tick.get("time").toString();
                    double bid = Double.parseDouble(tick.get("bid").toString());
                    double ask = Double.parseDouble(tick.get("ask").toString());

                    System.out.println(instrument);
                    System.out.println(time);
                    System.out.println(bid);
                    System.out.println(ask);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // print error message
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(responseString);
        }

    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you reduce your code down to a minimal amount to reproduce the issue!

Comment: I am trying to connect to https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com.  Because it is a secure login to access this api, there is a String access_token = "ACCESS-TOKEN" and String account_id = "1234567" that needs to get passed in the header to verify the login.  I am trying to do this in Java without maven....they are using "HTTPClient" and "HttpClientBuilder" which are maven classes. I just want to use a direct URLConnection to access https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com without a maven architype.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "maven"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're asking how to use the standard library instead of any dependencies and encode the account_id/access token as part of basic auth header. I would suggest using [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). It's included as part of the Java standard library. Try the following:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
String encoded = Base64.encode(account_id+":"+access_token);
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
```

Comment: Yes.  I pretty familiar with Java Programming, and I have not worked with networking using the HttpUrlConnection class.  I guess I asked my questions backwards. Thank you for your help, Jon.